# Can magento do custom quotes with link to cart?

Tags: shopping-cart

I have a problem with our store and selling that i keep coming across.
What do others do??

We sell online a lot but often get telephone inquiries from customers who build a package from many of our products combined.

we want to be able to email our customers a link that takes them straight to our shopping cart loaded with the products we have talked about / agreed upon. and then possibly apply custom pricing if we have offered a deal over the phone.

We have looked around and cant find an extension that would do this.

What do other online retailers do?
or is there a way to do this?

Thanks
Dano
UK

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interesting topic that inspired me to implement a **proof of concept** here:

https://github.com/aleron75/mageo2cq

It is based on the fact that when you create an order for a specific customer in the Admin Panel, a **not-active quote is created and linked to current customer**.

You can add items in the order, change prices, apply coupons and so on; all these **changes are saved** to the not-active quote even if you don't submit the order.

I simply added a **button** in the "Create Order" view which lets you set the current not-active quote as the **current active quote** for the customer.

**Pay attention:** this action is not reversible: when the customer logs in he will loose its old cart and find the cart assembled by the store manager in the Admin Panel.

Once the assembled quote is ready, simply email the customer to log in and he will find the updated cart.

**Note:** if the customer has some items in the cart before being logged in, the current anonymous cart will be merged with the saved one.

**Warning:** it's a proof of concept, I didn't test the module for production, test it carefully.

**Installation:** if you are not familiar with "modman" or "composer" simply get the zip package and copy/paste the content of "src" folder into your Magento root. Please, backup files and database before trying to install the module.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Alessandro

Thank you for your thoughts and concept.

My issue would be that these customers calling us do not have an account on our magento store already. They are calling to discuss with an interest in products and this leads to a purchase.

We currently have an extension in place that automatically creates an account for a guest customer after a purchase - customer is emailed a pass word.

Comment: The ideal flow (from a store owners viewpoint) would be;
1. customer calls or emails (sales lead)
2. we discuss correct products for them and make offer
3. we email them a quotation / details of the offer and on that quotation we include a link (unique to them)
4. link loads our cart page with the products already in basket plus any special deal / discount we have offered.
5. guest Customer makes purchase online
6. guest customer is automatically converted to login customer by existing app

Is there any way this could be possible?

What do you think?

Comment: You can create the customer in the Admin Panel during the call and associate the order cart as my extension does.
When customer receives the registration confirmation e-mail and logs in he/she also finds the cart. This also eliminates the possible problem with merged carts.
This is the easiest solution which exploits what you already have and doesn't require further customization.
It's a "good enough" solution to validate the idea; in case it works you can spend time and money in more usable solution in the future.
Sincerely.

Comment: Interesting stuff... yes this could work and is certainly worth a trial run! 
Are you an extension developer?
Thanks

Comment: Among other things yes I develop Magento extensions; most of them are on my GitHub account: https://github.com/aleron75/
If you think my solution was helpful, please up-vote/accept my answer, it will help my ranking. Thank you.